# arab country development guideline

Tags: utf-8, arabic

I'm not sure how to describe this question but I will ask it anyway. 
Lets say my company is developing some software and it has to be exported to another country. 
For the language part we only have to set up the encoding format to utf-8.
But for most Arab countries their systems or documents read from right to left. 
[image: window fliped]

Even though the window system is flipped...
is there any common guideline format for Arab countries?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main concerns when you are targeting Arabic users are an **appropriate character encoding** which you used `utf8` for, and support for **right-to-left** text and layout directions.

As for guidelines, W3C has a **[guide](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir)** to better understand how to markup up right-to-left text on a Web page.

Moreover, **Google Fonts** provides many [Arabic web fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=arabic) which you can use in your website.

You can also see **examples** of websites that target Arabic users to get inspiration. For example, [1](https://www.iau.edu.sa/ar), [2](http://www.colorslab.net/), [3](http://www.aljazeera.net/portal), [4](https://twitter.com/?lang=ar), [5](http://www.bbc.com/arabic/world), [6](https://www.ibda3world.com/), [7](https://www.edraak.org/), [8](http://maqola.org/), [9](https://ar-ar.facebook.com/), [10](http://www.amirifont.org/), etc